# Javascript How to return an array with odd numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return an array of numbers

```js
    function numbers(l, r) {
      // l and r are any given numbers
      var x=[];
      var i=l;
      while(x.push(i++)<r){};
      return x;        
    }


console.log(numbers(10, 19));
```

So far so good. Now I want to get the odd numbers. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You're basically asking, how to add `2` to `i` ..?

Comment: note odd numbers can be described as `2n + 1` where `n` is a member of the integers

Comment: "So far so good." - sure? Try running your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x.filter(n => n%2)` will keep only odd numbers.

if `n` is even, `n%2` will return 0 and the item will be removed by the filter.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

let odds = arr.filter(n => n%2)

console.log(odds)
```

Comment: OP's question accept 2 numbers not, an array!

Answer (score 2):

```js
function* numbers(start, end) {
    let i = start%2 ? start : ++start;
    while(i <= end) {
        yield i;
        i += 2
    }
}

console.log([...numbers(2, 10)])
```

or

```js
class Odd {
    constructor(l, r) {
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let i = this.l % 2 ? this.l : ++(this.l);
        while (i <= this.r) {
            yield i;
            i += 2
        }
    }
}

const odd = new Odd(2,10);

console.log([...odd])
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided two values `l` (starting point) and `r` (ending point) you would create your array from `l` to `r` in increments of +1. Use that array to filter the desired values that meet the `mod 2` or `% 2` criteria. FYI `mod 2` returns `0` if the value is an even number or `1` if the value is an odd number. The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Do note that in JavaScript `0` is a `falsy` value so only positive integer values like 1 are returned thus the array is formed with all values that resulted in `n % 2` equal to 1.

```
function oddNumbers(l, r) {
    let arr = [];
    while (l <= r) {
        arr.push(l);
        l += 1;
    };
    return arr.filter(n => n % 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an appropriate start value and increment by `2` for each pushing.

```js
function numbers(l, r) {
    var x = [],
        i = Math.floor(l / 2) * 2 + 1; // start with an odd number

    while(i <= r) {
        x.push(i);
        i += 2;
    };
    return x;        
}

console.log(numbers(10, 19));
console.log(numbers(3, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, make i odd:

```
i = i+1-i%2;
```

Then iterate over every second:

```
 while(x.push(i+=2)<r){};
```

Note that this returns *r-1* numbers and not *numbers up to r-1*

---

Shorter

```
var EverySecond = (start,length) => Array.from({length}).map((el,i)=>start+i*2);
var even = (start,length) => EverySecond(start+start%2,length);
var odd = (start,length) => EverySecond(start+1-start%2,length);
```

Comment: Do we need to make sure l is odd? (To ensure i is odd)

Answer (score 0):

1 - first create an array with all numbers between n and p.

2- create a second array to collect all odd numbers using For loop.

In For loop, collect all odd numbers using `Math.floor()` method. Any odd number divided by 2 will not be equal to the nearest integer created by `Math.floor()` and thus, that number will be included in the second array. All the even numbers will be filtered out as that even number divided 2 and `Math.floor()` integer divided by 2 will be of same value.

Code:

```js
function numbers(n, p) {
  let allArr = [];

  for (let i = n; i <= p; i++) {
    allArr.push(i);
  }

  let result = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < allArr.length; j++) {
    if (allArr[j] / 2 !== Math.floor(allArr[j] / 2)) {
      result.push(allArr[j]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(numbers(10, 19));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for pairs:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].filter(function(n){ return n%2 === 0; });
```

Try this for odds:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].filter(function(n){ return n%2 !== 0; });
```