# how to read every odd value from below array list:

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

My dropdown values displaying as:

```
The
Are
company
we
belongsto
yes
America
can
```

I run this code, and i got above result in console:

```
let arr = [];
let appswitcherlist = await profileidentity.profile_profile_Appswitcherdropdownlist.each((ele, index) => {

    if (ele != undefined) {
        ele.getText().then((text) => {
            arr.push(text);
        });
    }
});
console.log(arr); // check what you get here.
const oddItems = arr.filter((item, index) => index%2 == 0)
console.log(oddItems); //check what you get here. You should bind this to drop-down.
```

I want to read every odd row as below:

```
The
company
belongsto
America
```

Comment: `let odds = array.filter((e,i) => i%2)`

Comment: do you have gathered the data in some variable ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript How to return an array with odd numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570965/javascript-how-to-return-an-array-with-odd-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. Where the Filter method on array is used.

```
let arr = ['The', 'Are', 'company', 'we', 'belongsto', 'yes', 'America', 'can'];
const oddItems = arr.filter((item, index) => index%2 == 0)

console.log(oddItems);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/26y0vmbp/3/

Comment: Hi @Sagar ,currently the text is displaying the output .How can i take those values in to one array of variable?

Comment: can you share your code snippet or can you update your question to have the updated code.. so i can give it a try..

Comment: When i run below code,the console displaying the result as:var appswitcherlist=await profileidentity.profile_profile_Appswitcherdropdownlist.each((ele,index) => {
    

        if (ele != undefined) {

            ele.getText().then((text) => {

                
                console.log(text);

            });
        }
    });The
Are
company
we
belongsto
yes
America
can

Comment: Instead of console.log -- do arr.push(text);     And define arr on top of your existing code. So that arr is accessible inside. After your code, arr will have all the values. And then you run my code.. which will filter all values.

Comment: Something like this:
let arr = [];
var appswitcherlist=await profileidentity.profile_profile_Appswitcherdropdownlist.each((ele,index) => { 
 if (ele != undefined) { 
  ele.getText().then((text) => { 
   arr.push(text);
  }); 
 } 
});

Comment: I am getting this result as same,and i update my code please check.[
  'The\n' +
    'Are\n' +
    'company\n' +
    'we\n' +
    'belongsto\n' +
    'yes\n' +
    'America\n' +
    'can\n' +

]

Comment: I see you have not declared arr as an array on top of your code. And inside your code, you need to do -- arr.push(text); This part is missing.

Comment: i updated the code and still displaying same.

Comment: After your code and before the filter, can you console.log(arr) and see what are the contents of arr?

Comment: Before filter:

The
Are
company
we
belongsto
yes
America
can

Comment: console.log(oddItems) -- doesnt give you items? check which variable you have bind to your drop-down. it should be oddItems. Also change const arr = []  --> let arr = [];

Comment: @RajeshT - I updated your post. Can you give it a try.

Comment: console.log(arr) ,correctly taken the values.But after filter,its added \n+ to the list.Below is result:[ 'The\n' + 'Are\n' + 'company\n' + 'we\n' + 'belongsto\n' + 'yes\n' + 'America\n' + 'can\n' + ]

Comment: console.log(arr) displaying as,The are company we belongsto yes America can which causing error it should display as The ,are ,company ,we ,belongsto, yes, America ,can...correct where i am wrong

Comment: ‘\n’ is not added by my code.. I guess it’s returned from the API you are calling. You can replace that text as well while adding to the arr array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `(index % 2 !== 0)` to your existing condition, like below.

```js
var appswitcherlist = await profileidentity.profile_profile_Appswitcherdropdownlist.each((ele, index) => {
  if (ele != undefined && (index % 2 !== 0)) {
    ele.getText().then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Sayem ,i have added the below mentioned condition and its not displaying any values.

Answer (score 0):

```
let listData = [
  'The',
  'Are',
  'company',
  'we',
  'belongsto',
  'yes',
  'America',
  'can',
]
let i = 0;
for(let row of listData){
   i++;
   if(i%2){
      console.log(row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['The', 'Are', 'company', 'we', 'belongsto', 'yes', 'America', 'can'];
let oddItems = [];

for(a in arr){
    a%2 === 0 ? oddItems.push(arr[a]) : null ;
}

console.log(oddItems);
```

Comment: Hi @Bharath,can you do changes based on my code.a%2 ==0 showing error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is really simple after the introduction of await, don't need to complicate it

First disable selenium control flow in config file, just add this line in config file:

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow

Now in test use:

```
it('Some test name', async function() {

    let arr=[]
    let appswitcherlist=await profileidentity.profile_profile_Appswitcherdropdownlist.getText()
    const oddItems=appswitcherlist.filter((item, index)= > index % 2 == 0)
    console.log(oddItems)
})
```